# Curl post null object

Tags: c++, http, curl, post, libcurl

I used example code from curl's help, but server receives empty objects and null custom header. GET method works fine. `strbuf.GetString()` - it's json object which converted to String.

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
struct WriteThis pooh;
res = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; 
curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");  
curl_slist_append( headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_slist_append( headers, "charset: utf-8"); 
curl_slist_append( headers, "AuthToken: 9BA1B05482567E64037573FFB68672DCB52E4993"); 
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) 
{
  pooh.readptr = strbuf.GetString();
  pooh.sizeleft = (long)strlen(strbuf.GetString());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &pooh);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers); 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,writer);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, &pooh);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, pooh.sizeleft);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if (CURLE_OK == res) 
  { 
    char *ct;         
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
    if((CURLE_OK == res) && ct){    

                         }
  }
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();

struct WriteThis {
    const char *readptr;
    long sizeleft;
};

static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    struct WriteThis *pooh = (struct WriteThis *)userp;

    if(size*nmemb < 1)
        return 0;

    if(pooh->sizeleft) {
        *(char *)ptr = pooh->readptr[0]; /* copy one single byte */ 
        pooh->readptr++;                 /* advance pointer */ 
        pooh->sizeleft--;                /* less data left */ 
        return 1;                        /* we return 1 byte at a time! */ 
    }

    return 0;                          /* no more data left to deliver */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead:

```
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL; 
curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");  
curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_slist_append(headers, "charset: utf-8"); 
curl_slist_append(headers, "AuthToken: 9BA1B05482567E64037573FFB68672DCB52E4993"); 
curl = curl_easy_init();
```

This:

```
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL; 
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");  
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charset: utf-8"); 
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "AuthToken: 9BA1B05482567E64037573FFB68672DCB52E4993"); 
curl = curl_easy_init();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You set *both* a read callback and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. That's not useful.  You need to decide which way you want to provide the data. In this case, I believe it will use the POSTFIELDS and just ignore the read callback.
2. The pointer you pass to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is not a string so libcurl will send funny binary "garbage" from there. You probably want to pass in `pooh.readptr` there.